# Help with basic modular arithmetic question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I [asked this question moments ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4041415/242) but it was closed despite the link being non-applicable to my question. I need help solving the below basic modular problem,

> Show that $39$ divides $17^{48}-5^{24}$

My course has NOT covered Fermat's Theorem. The only properties of modular arithmetic I know are additivity, multiplicativity, symmetry, and transitivity. My professor wants me to solve this question only using these basic properties, but I have honestly no idea how to do so. I don't know what pattern I'm supposed to recognize.

Comment: It's easy to see that $3$ divides it, but I don't see a quick way for $13$ yet.

Comment: At first glance I see that 39 = 2 * 17  + 5, maybe difference of squares could help?

Comment: Well... it sucks a bit, but you could calculate the first few powers of $17$ and $5 \bmod 39$. For example: $17^2 = 289\equiv 16\bmod 39$. Then $17^3\equiv 17\cdot 16...$ etc. And see where it takes you (good places).

Comment: As other responses have indicated: [1] attack the (mod 3) and (mod 13) congruences separately [2] note that by binomial expansion, $(a + nb)^k \equiv a^k \pmod{n} ~:~ a,b,n,k \in \mathbb{Z^+}.$ [3] $17 = 4 + 13$, so when checking congruence (mod 13), you can immediately replace $(17)$ with $(4)$.

Comment: Re previous comment, a cursory examination of powers of $(4) \pmod{13}$ reveals $4^2 = 3 \implies 4^4 = 3^2 = -4 \implies 4^8 = 3^4 = (-4)^2 = 3 = 4^2 \implies 4^{(8-2)} = 1.$  Similarly, $5^2 = -1 \implies 5^4 = 1.$

Comment: Note that with $r,a,k,n \in \mathbb{Z^+},$ then considering equivalences (mod $n$), $~\{r^a = 1\} \implies r^{(ak)} = \left(r^a\right)^k = (1)^k = 1.$

Comment: For rigor: if $n,a$ are relatively prime and $n|(ab)$, then $n|b$.  Applying this, if $r,n$ are relatively prime, then working with congruences (mod $n$), with $a > b,$ $~r^a = r^b \implies n|(r^a - r^b) = (r^b)\left(r^{(a-b)} - 1\right).$  This implies $n|\left(r^{(a-b)} - 1\right) \implies r^{(a-b)} = 1.$

Comment: Please don't duplicate your closed questions - this violates site policy. It was already [explained](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4041415/help-solving-basic-modular-arithmetic-problem/4041424#comment8345898_4041424) in your prior question how to avoid use of little Fermat.  If that comment was not clear then you should have asked for clarification *there*.

Comment: What gives you the right to state whether or not I have received the explanation I need? The answer you gave on my previous question was useless to me. I have no understanding of the "linked order reduction" concept nor does my textbook discuss that topic. The explanations I received on this question were immensely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two exponents are *very* even (meaning have many factors of $2$), so let's apply difference of squares a few times, hoping that we can get a useful factor that is much smaller.

\begin{align*}
17^{48} - 5^{24} &= (17^{24} - 5^{12})(17^{24} + 5^{12})  \\
    &= (17^{12} - 5^{6})(17^{12} + 5^{6})(17^{24} + 5^{12})  \\
    &= (17^{6} - 5^{3})(17^{6} + 5^{3})(17^{12} + 5^{6})(17^{24} + 5^{12})
\end{align*}

$39 = 3 \cdot 13$.  If $3$ divides any of these factors and $13$ divides any of these factors, $39$ divides the original quantity.  If $3$ divides a quantity, that quantity is congruent to $0 \pmod{3}$.  If $13$ divides a quantity, that quantity is congruent to $0 \pmod{13}$.

Let's compute $17^6  - 5^3 \pmod{3}$.  \begin{align*}
17^6 &\cong (-1)^6 \pmod{3}  \\
    &\cong 1 \pmod{3}  \text{ and }  \\
5^3 &\cong 1^3 \pmod{3}  \\
    &\cong 1 \pmod{3}  \text{, so}  \\
17^6 - 5^3 &\cong 1 - 1 \pmod{3}  \\
    &\cong 0 \pmod{3}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Therefore, $3$ divides the first factor.

Now let's compute $17^6  - 5^3 \pmod{13}$.  It is useful to note that $6 = 4+2 = 110_2$ in binary, so $17^6 = 17^{4+2} = 17^4 \cdot 17^2$ and we can get $17^4$ by squaring $17^2$.  (For more on this, see [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) and its application to [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method).)
\begin{align*}
17^2 &\cong (4)^2 \pmod{13}  \\
    &\cong 16 \pmod{13}  \\
    &\cong 3 \pmod{13}  \text{ and }  \\
17^4 &\cong (17^2)^2 \pmod{13}  \\
    &\cong (3)^2 \pmod{13}  \\
    &\cong 9 \pmod{13}  \text{ so }  \\
17^6 &\cong 17^4 \cdot 17^2 \pmod{13}  \\
    &\cong 9 \cdot 3 \pmod{13}  \\
    &\cong 27 \pmod{13}  \\
    &\cong 1 \pmod{13}  \text{ and also }  \\
5^3 &\cong 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \pmod{13}  \\
    &\cong 25 \cdot 5 \pmod{13}  \\
    &\cong (-1) \cdot 5 \pmod{13}  \\
    &\cong 8 \cdot 5 \pmod{13}  \text{ so }  \\
17^6 - 5^3 &\cong 1 - 8 \pmod{13}  \\
    &\cong -7 \pmod{13}  \\
    &\cong 6 \pmod{13}  \text{.}
\end{align*}

So $13$ doesn't divide the first factor.  How about the second factor?  \begin{align*}
17^6 + 5^3 &\cong 1 + 8 \pmod{13}  \\
    &\cong 9 \pmod{13}
\end{align*}

Nope.  The third factor?  \begin{align*}
17^{12} + 5^6 &\cong (17^6)^2 + (5^3)^2 \pmod{13}  \\
    &\cong 1^2 + 8^2 \pmod{13}  \\
    &\cong 65 \pmod{13}  \\
    &\cong 5 \cdot 13 \pmod{13}  \\
    &\cong 0 \pmod{13}  \\
\end{align*}

So $13$ divides the third factor.  Therefore, $39$ divides the given quantity.

---

Here's another method that is more direct.

\begin{align*}
17^{48} - 5^{24}
    &\cong 17^{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 } - 5^{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2}  \pmod{39}  \\
    &\cong (17^3)^{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 } - (5^3)^{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2}  \pmod{39}  \\
    &\cong (4913)^{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 } - (125)^{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2}  \pmod{39}  \\
    &\cong (125\cdot 39 + 38)^{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 } - (3 \cdot 39 + 8)^{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2}  \pmod{39}  \\
    &\cong (38)^{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 } - (8)^{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2}  \pmod{39}  & & \text{[alt.: note that $38 \cong -1 \pmod{39}$]}  \\
    &\cong (38^2)^{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 } - (8^2)^{2 \cdot 2}  \pmod{39}  \\
    &\cong (37 \cdot 39 +1)^{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 } - (1 \cdot 39 + 25)^{2 \cdot 2}  \pmod{39}  \\
    &\cong (1)^{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 } - (25)^{2 \cdot 2}  \pmod{39}  \\
    &\cong 1 - (25)^{2 \cdot 2}  \pmod{39}  \\
    &\cong 1 - (25^2)^{2}  \pmod{39}  \\
    &\cong 1 - (16 \cdot 39 + 1)^{2}  \pmod{39}  
    &\cong 1 - (1)^{2}  \pmod{39}  \\
    &\cong 0  \pmod{39}  \text{,}
\end{align*}
so $39$ divides the gven quantity.

Answer (score 1):

Well $\mod 3$ it's easy to see $17^{48} - 5^{24} \equiv (-1)^{48}-(-1)^{24} \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ so $3|17^{48}-5^{24}$.

And $\mod {13}$ we see $17^{48} - 5^{24} \equiv 4^{48} - 5^{24}\equiv 16^{24} - 5^{24} \equiv 3^{24}-5^{24}\pmod {13}$

Now... can't use Fermat (which makes short work) so we use sequential squaring.

$3^2\equiv 9$ and $3^3 \equiv 27 \equiv 1\pmod {13}$.  And $5^2 \equiv 25 \equiv -1\pmod {13}$

So $3^{24} - 5^{24} \equiv 27^8 - 25^{12} \equiv 1^8 - (-1)^{12} \equiv 1 - 1 \equiv 0\pmod{13}$

So $13|17^{48} - 5^{24}$.

So $\operatorname{lcm}(3,13) = 39|17^{48} - 5^{24}$.

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide two proofs. The second one is probaly the one you're looking for

$17^{48}-5^{24}=(17^{16})^3-(5^{4})^6(mod 39)$

By Euler Totient Theorem, you have thats equal to

$1^3-1^6=1-1=0(mod 39)$, Thus, it is divisible by 39

Second proof:

$17^{48}=(17^2)^{24}=(-1)^{24}=1 (mod39) $

$5^{24}=(5^3)^8=8^8=(8^4)^2=1^2=1 (mod 39)$

Together, you get $1-1=0 (mod 39)$. Thus, it is proven

Comment: "My course has NOT covered Fermat's Theorem. The only properties of modular arithmetic I know are additivity, multiplicativity, symmetry, and transitivity"

Comment: I just used multiplicativity and additivity in the second proof